# setInterval, clearInterval instance out of scope

Tags: typescript, ionic3, setinterval

In Ionic3, I made a interval that refresh my data and I want it to stop when leaving the view. But I've been unable to scope the interval instance...
Note that this is my first step in typescript....

```
updateData(){    
  var interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.getdata.getData().subscribe( data => {
      this.channels = data.channels;
    })
  },2000);
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
  clearInterval(interval);//[TS]Cannot find name 'interval'
  console.log('leave view');
}
```

Comment: subscribing like that is pretty inefficient. why do you need to re subscribe, if `getData()` is implemented correctly, then you don't need to `setInterval`

Comment: how should I undate the data without susbcribe ? as I said... I'm really a beginner. get method is only a http get.

Comment: Okay just leave it as it is then, rxjs is super confusing in the beginning (the subscribe line)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply move the variable to an outer scope e.g.

```
interval: number; // Moved it out. 

updateData(){    
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.getdata.getData().subscribe( data => {
      this.channels = data.channels;
    });
  },2000);
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
  console.log('leave view');
}
```

Comment: Update: Declare interval as

`interval: NodeJS.Timer;`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete Observable solution

```
subscription: Subscription;

updateData(){
    const interval = Rx.Observable.interval(2000).flatMap(() => this.getdata.getData());
    subscription = interval.subscribe(data => { this.channels = data.channels; });
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
    console.log('leave view');
}
```

When you are using Observable, then it is often good use it consistently

Comment: Good suggestion. i will not say I understand what make the difference.. :P. But in witch module did I import Subscription object? I can't find it.[Edit] ok dummy, visual studio code suggest it for me :'rxjs/Subscription'

Comment: Ok now... Rx object have to be define or include how and where?.. :P

Comment: `import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";`
`import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";` I am not really sure what you mean?

Comment: const interval = Rx.Observable.interval...: cannot find name "Rx"

Comment: Found it.. : import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';